# Wall Menu Font Size and Type recommendation

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I am designing my own restaurant wall menu and would like some help with choosing  which font size is best for the heading, the menu items and also the font that is most suitable.

Thank you for reading

Lindsey

Comment: What size is the menu?

Comment: It depends on how much room you have to work with, the distance from the person and the menu and what type of font you use. Asking for a font that is most suitable is pretty broad, there could be many suitable serif and san-serif fonts.

Comment: There are 5 boards, 460x800. The standing distance is approx 3metres from the menu

Comment: This also depends on your content. Why not post some basic drafts so we can get a better view. Or go to a MCD and study their menus :)

Comment: Whatever you use, please, for the love of guacamole, MAKE SURE EVERYTHING IS ALIGNED ON TOP. There was a Mexican place by my office which had four signs where the copy lined up on top and one sign (the second of five, not even the middle) with text which started two inches lower. Made me insane every time I walked in. (The food was really good, so I kept coming back, but those MENUS!)

Comment: @Lindsey: What units? (Also please [edit] additional information into your question.)

Comment: Whatever you choose, do some tests on paper that have words at the sizes you are thinking about, and have people look at them in the context and at the distance you will be positioning them, remembering to include nearsighted people without their glasses on. Preferably multiple lines of type, since line height/information density is a factor in reading and comprehension. Comprehension is paramount.

Comment: This question is quite broad as it is. What kind of restaurant? what type of food? how many items in this menu? what colors (wall / font)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a whole bunch of variables that we can't account for:

- typeface
- type style
- colors/contrast
- height of menu
- distance menu is from viewers
- etc.

Best way to figure this out? Print out some samples, put them on the wall, and ask people to read them.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the font according to the composition i make. Cause composition will change everything . If you use a blackboard concept i would go and look for COMIC and handwriting freehand fonts. In that case I'd use Uppercase all. But if its a classical fancy decoration it changes. 
What is better to use simple but cute, non condensed and square layout fonts so it can be clearly read from far.

Comment: Thank you. The menus will be printed and mounted on foam board, I'm hoping to keep a very clean design.

Answer (score 0):

The font you choose should depend on the type of restaurant you run.
We need more information on this to help.

The font size also depends on the font itself:
fonts are designed to look good in a certain size.
Some are more appropriate in signs or menus than others.

Comment: Just realized this was an old question.

Comment: I actually don't agree with the font = type of restaurant. That often leads to really cliche design (Papyrus = middle easter food!, Script face = French!, Blackletter = German food!).